# Get count of rows having values in ascending sequence like 1,2,3 until a break occurs like 1,2,3,7,8,9,10 from table

Tags: mysql, ip, cidr, static-ip-address

ip_available Table data is:

| ip_address | parent |
| --- | --- |
| 10010010024 | 1987 |
| 10010010026 | 1987 |
| 10010010027 | 1987 |
| 10010010033 | 1987 |
| 10010010034 | 1987 |
| 10010010035 | 1987 |
| 10010010036 | 1987 |
| 10010010037 | 1987 |
| 10010010090 | 2010 |

Similarly there are more ip_addresses with other parent values

I want result set like

| ip_address_min | parent | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10010010024 | 1987 | 3 |
| 10010010033 | 1987 | 5 |
| 10010010090 | 2010 | 1 |

DB is MySQL
Count should come for each regular sequence, No matter if parent value is repeated.

Comment: This is a [Gaps&Island-Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gaps-and-islands). It would help if you could specify your MySQL version (e.g. if you use MySQL 8 or not).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little more details would help out next time, like including your table structure.
But I believe this will help you out.

```
SELECT MIN(ip_address) as ip_address_min, MIN(parent) as parent, COUNT(ip_address) as count 
FROM ip_available
GROUP BY LEFT(ip_address,length(ip_address)-1);
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5dw4hvSfLm5idNjknrj6YX/0

Comment: This won't work if the numbers span different 10's (e.g. ....39, .....40).